# Script for Removing part URL at htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, redirect

I have Url : 
https://example.com/edun?fbclid=IwAR3r-md77G9VQGkHvowhcCVF6kOAg7f43prXv5gCLLiefEG1EMzE3CTJNc0

I want to change this link above to :
https://example.com/edun

How to do this at .htaccess ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

fbclid is evil :D

you can use something like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?+&+fbclid=[^&]+((?!&?).)*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /$1? [R=302,NE]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)?+&+fbclid=[^&]+&?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1%1%2 [R=302,L,NE]
```

and you also must have `mod_rewrite` in your appache available and enabled

Comment: Thanks for comment bro, Yes fbclid is evil :D

I already  tried your script but still doesn't work.

Now i'am using Page RUle of Cloudflare to Redirect
https://auraku.id/*?fbclid=*     to  https://auraku.id/$1